# How to create a valid svg element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, constructor, console

I was working with SVG and i created an svg element. I added a `<rect>` element directly into the svg with html and then I created a new element (without namespace) `<circle>` with javascript and appended it to the svg element. The  `<rect>` element displayed in the svg viewbox but the `<circle>` element did not display.

I got the `<rect>` and `<circle>` on the console and checked the constructor. The `<rect>` element returned `SVGRectElement` but the `<circle>` returned `HTMLUnknownElement`. I created a new `<circle>` element (with namespace: https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) and checked the constructor which returned `Element`.

Whichever way, appending both the namespaced and non-namespaced `<circle>` element to the svg did not appear in the svg viewbox. So how do i create a recognized svg element with javascript that will return `SVGCircleElement?`.

```js
   var circle = document.createElement('circle');
    circle.setAttribute('cx', '10');
    circle.setAttribute('cy', '10');  
    circle.setAttribute('r', '30');
    circle.setAttribute('fill', 'red');

    var circle_2 = document.createElementNS('https://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
    circle.setAttribute('cx', '5');
    circle.setAttribute('cy', '20');  
    circle.setAttribute('r', '30');
    circle.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');

    var svg = document.getElementById('svgx');
    var rect = document.getElementById('svgrect');
    svg.appendChild(circle);
    svg.appendChild(circle_2);

    console.log(svg.constructor); // SVGSVGElement() { [native code] }
    console.log(rect.constructor); // HTMLRectElement() { [native code] }
    console.log(circle.constructor); // HTMLUnknownElement() { [native code] }
    console.log(circle_2.constructor); // Element() { [native code] }
```

```html
<svg style='width: 100%;' id='svgx'>
<rect x='5' y='5' width='50' height='30' fill='black' id='svgrect'>
</svg>
```

Comment: 1. You need to close the `<rect>` like this: `id='svgrect' />` or like this: `id='svgrect'></rect>` and 2. Use always `createElementNS`

Comment: Sorry about my code error in this question. I closed all my tag properly in my code

Comment: As visible in my javascript code, the second circle i create was with namespace and it returned `function Element() { [native code] }` which also did not display in the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "s" from "https".

```
var circle_2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
```

Even though it looks like a URL. It is really just a string constant that indicates this XML file is an SVG file.  The namespace constant has to be exactly as presented here.

Also you need to change `circle` to `circle_2` for that section of code.

```js
var circle_2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
circle_2.setAttribute('cx', '5');
circle_2.setAttribute('cy', '20');  
circle_2.setAttribute('r', '30');
circle_2.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');

var svg = document.getElementById('svgx');
var rect = document.getElementById('svgrect');
svg.appendChild(circle_2);
```

```html
<svg style='width: 100%;' id='svgx'>
<rect x='5' y='5' width='50' height='30' fill='black' id='svgrect'>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've been making different approaches towards this for 3 days only to figure out now that removing an 's' in namespace was the solution. Really interesting. Thanks Paul