# Is there a way to extend SVGElement like HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, svg, frontend

I'm making a small JS library. I was creating custom elements using the HTMLElement interface. Now I want to make a custom graphing tool and for that, I want my element to extend SVGElement.

I have a class **Graph.js** which extends SVGElement and a **main.js** which instantiates a graph.

This is my class **Graph.js** :

```
export class Graph extends SVGElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

    }

}
```

and **Main.js**:

```
import { Graph } from './Experimental/Graph/Graph.js';

customElements.define('pro-graph', Graph);

let graph = new Graph();
```

But for some reason I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor.
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

Comment: Nope. The Custom Elements API can only extend HTMLElement. You can extend other  HTML Elements ... BUT.. Apple said it won't implement that part of the spec. So cross browser you can only go with HTMLElement. I have given many SVG and Web Components answers lately: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2520800+%5Bsvg%5D+web+component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the line `super();` in your constructor is equivalent to `new SVGElement()`, which throws that exact exception when you call it directly. It also doesn't make much sense to try this, because there are no "pure" `SVGElement`s. `SVGElement` is an abstract base-class for more specialized elements like `SVGCircleElement`, `SVGPathElement` and all the others. But those can't be created through a constructor either. The usual way to create an SVG element is through the factory method `document.createElementNS` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206823/how-to-create-a-valid-svg-element-with-javascript).

When you can not instantiate a class through a constructor, then you can not create a class extending it.

A better approach to your library design might be:

- Create a wrapper class which doesn't extend SVGElement but instead has an SVGElement in a private variable. If you want your objects to work within any existing code that uses SVGElements as if it were one, then you just need to implement the whole interface by forwarding the function calls to the corresponding functions of the wrapped SVGElement. This pattern is called a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).
- Create an SVGElement and then attach a couple additional methods to it. This requires a lot less code than creating a decorator for an interface as large as SVGElement, but has the risk that you might overwrite functions that might get added in a future version of the SVG spec or undocumented but important functions added by the SVG implementation of the web browser.

Comment: "The problem is that the line super(); in your constructor is equivalent to new SVGElement(), which throws that exact exception when you call it directly." The same is true for `new HTMLElement()`, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use the same construct as you, @StackThePile. I was trying to extend `SVGElement` so that I could take advantage of IntelliSense and TypeScript for DevEx purposes. Here was my base class ...

```
export class SvgBase extends SVGElement {
    svgNameSpace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    /** @ts-ignore */
    constructor(type: string) {
        const element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);
        if (!element) throw new Error(`We had trouble creating a ${type} SVG element`);
        /** @ts-ignore */
        return element;
    }
}
```

My goal was to be able to do things like this, down the road ...

```
class MySvgRect extends SvgBase {
    constructor() {
        super("rect");
        this.setAttribute("x", "20"); // or something
    }
}
```

Returning the element from the constructor in `SvgBase` was my hack to "extend" SVGElement, even though the class isn't extendable, per @Philipp's answer. This actually worked in my Vite project, too! However, it fails in production because (1) the constructor doesn't call `super()`, and I can't fix it because (2) you can't extend SVGElement using the `customComponent.define` API.

My solution was to turn my base class into a constructor function, playing around with the types a bit to to tell TypeScript that it satisfies the constraints for a constructor. Again, this is *just* for the purposes of IntelliSense.

```
const SvgBase = function(type:string) {
    let svgNameSpace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    const element = document.createElementNS(svgNameSpace, type);

    if (!element) throw new Error(`We had trouble creating a ${type} SVG element`);
    return element as SVGElement;
}  as any as { new(type:string): SVGElement }
```

You could use this pattern to create a whole slew of custom SVG components, too. However, I assume your use case is more declarative, where you'd like to have users manually write tag names into their html (and have them show up as such when you inspect it). If you can, try to wrap your custom SVGs in a containing HTMLElement, defining it using `customElements.define`.